# Can't Restore Samsung Galaxy S3 To Factory Firmware

Tags: heimdall, factory-image

I installed CyanogenMod on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGH i747), and now I need to re-install factory firmware to network unlock my phone. Heimdall seems to be able to successfully image the firmware package onto the device, but after imaging, it won't boot. I can still get to recovery mode and download mode, but nothing else. This is the command I'm using to image:

```
heimdall flash --SYSTEM I747UCDLK3_I747ATTDLK3_I747UCDLK3_HOME.tar.md5
```

This is the output:

```
Heimdall v1.4.1

Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading SYSTEM
100%
SYSTEM upload successful

Ending session...
Rebooting device...
Releasing device interface...
```

I tried factory resetting before and after imaging the ROM via ClockworkMod, but it didn't help.

**How do I fix this?**

---

**NOTE**: I am using Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tar.md5` file is used by Odin (another firmware flashing tool), but AFAIK it cannot be used by Heimdall. Please make a backup of this file.

## Remove md5sum

Run `md5sum` on any file to see what is it's output like. Something similar will be appended to original `.tar` file. Assuming you can open the `.tar.md5` file in a text editor, remove the md5 sum from the end of file (and probably you'll have to remove last `new line` character). Then rename this file to `I747UCDLK3_I747ATTDLK3_I747UCDLK3_HOME.tar`.

## Extract partitions

You should be able to run `tar -xf I747UCDLK3_I747ATTDLK3_I747UCDLK3_HOME.tar`. It should create a new directory with similar name and this directory will contain images of boot, cache, fat, hidden, recovery and system partitions (and maybe more):

- boot.img
- cache.img.ext4
- hidden.img.ext4
- system.img.ext4

## Flashing

You should make sure that partitions on your device have the same names as I've written below (APPS, CACHE, HIDDEN, SYSTEM). You can do it be running `heimdall download-pit --output <filename>` and then `heimdall print-pit --file <filename>`. Finally, here's the actual flashing (you may want to add `--no-reboot` to the first command):

```
# heimdall flash --APPS boot.img --verbose
# heimdall flash --SYSTEM system.img.ext4 --CACHE cache.img.ext4 --HIDDEN hidden.img.ext4 --verbose
```

## Re-flash recovery (added later)

In case your phone boots to recovery instead of system, you should flash your recovery (doesn't have to be stock) image again.

Comment: there is no hidden.img.ext4, im going to skip that step

Comment: Gets pretty close, it finishes imaging all those (Exept hidden.img.ext4) then reboots into clockworkmod. I am greeted with a prompt asking if i want to install an untrusted zip (i selected yes). the phone then reboots a few times, then boots back into clockworkmod

Comment: It worked! im back at the factory firmware! Thanks!